# Copy from file: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "\N"

Tags: postgresql, psql

My table column defined intcol integer; no NOT NULL constraint. In the load  file most values are integers, but a few are null values labeled with the '\N' default as suggested by the copy manual. Can the copy command convert '\N' to null values in the table?  I also tried with null 'NA'. Got similar error message.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "\N"
CONTEXT:  COPY table_name, line 111, column position3: "\N"
```

Any trick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `NULL` parameter. From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

> NULL
>
> Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format.

Example

```
copy my_table from '/my/csv_file.csv' (format csv, null '\N');
```

Comment: Initially I thought it (\N) is the default, and you don't have to specify it.

Comment: @KeminZhou \N is the default if you are using the default format.  But once you switch the format to csv, the default is an unquoted empty string